# magento multi store - product URL based on store

Tags: magento-1.9, multistore

I'm building a magento site with 1 website, 2 stores and 1 store view for each store.
store URLs: domain.com/storea and domain.com/storeb

Everything goes well like cart share, login share, etc except for 1 thing,
when viewing the products in the cart, all products have the same URLs and they follow the current store name.

How to make products use the url to where the store they belong to?

Comment: thx for your comment. i didn't install any 3rd party extension. how does magento know which products belong to which store? i was about to override getProductUrl() to check product root category.

Comment: spoke to soon, i have cache disabled. opening up a store A and there are 2 products in cart ( and minicart), all products have url domain.com/storea/index.php/product-name, one of the product should have domain.com/storeb/index.php/product-name.

when going to store B, all producs in cart have /storea URL(yes, /storea not /storeb). any idea?

Comment: ah maybe the theme, i am using ultimo theme. ill check it out, thanks!

Comment: nope, i changed to modern theme and the problem is still there. do i have to use website instead of store to get the url working?